# Prove that the open set with some points on the edge is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

So I have the following problem I'm trying to figure out.

"Let $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | |x| < 1\}$ and let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | |x| = 1\}$. Prove that $B \cup C$ is convex for subset $ C\subseteq S$. "

Now, it's obvious that you can show using the triangle inequality and considering the edge cases for when ur endpoints on the line segment are linearly independent/dependent. I am wondering if there's a way to prove it more elegantly considering as little cases as possible. I wanna say there's a way to do that (since intuitively, it's very easy to imagine), but I just can't think of it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is $C$? Certainly not all subsets of $S$ are convex!

Comment: oops, my bad. Made a small typo. it's suppose to be the union of B and C that's convex.

Comment: I'm still confused. Obviously $B \cup C \subseteq S$ is false, regardless of $C$, because $0 \in B$, but $0 \notin S$.

Comment: I presume that you meant $S = \{ x \mid \|x\| \le 1 \}$.

Comment: Ok, that should clear it up. My apologies. I was not thinking straight last night. It's to prove $B\cup C$ that's convex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some assumptions on the norm the result is false. Take
$\|x\|_\infty = \max_k |x_k|$ and $C = \{e_1\pm e_2\} $. Then $B \cup C $, is not convex, as $e_1 ={1 \over 2} ((e_1+e_2)+ (e_1-e_2))\notin B \cup C$.

If $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm then there is a proof without cases, albeit the proof with cases is not particularly inelegant.

The key result is that if $x,y$ satisfy $\|x\| \le 1, \|y\| \le 1$, then $\langle x, y \rangle = 1$ **iff** $x=y$. In particular, if $x \neq y$ then $\langle x, y \rangle <1$. This follows from Cauchy Schwarz.

Suppose $x,y \in B \cup C$, with $x \neq y$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\|^2 &=&\lambda^2\|x\|^2 + (1-\lambda)^2 \|y\|^2 + 2 \lambda(1-\lambda) \langle x, y \rangle \\
&<& \lambda^2\|x\|^2 + (1-\lambda)^2 \|y\|^2 + 2 \lambda(1-\lambda) \\
&\le& \lambda^2 + (1-\lambda)^2  + 2 \lambda(1-\lambda) \\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray}
In particular, $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in B$.

Comment: in the iff statement the condition $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ is missing

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but I've just fixed the question. My apologies, the definition of $S$ was correct. It was to prove $B\cup C$ was a convex set where $C\subseteq S$. I agree that the proof with cases is not inelegant, I'm just trying to explore ways to prove it alternatively. Sorry about the confusion there!

Comment: @sharkeater123 I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Just to be clear, it was not me who downvoted.-> Just upvoted and accepted the answer